# How to increase ggplot font resolution in Jupyterhub

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter

I'm using `ggplot2` in a Jupyter environment (R version 4.1.2), but for some reason the resolution of the fonts is very low. I produced the following plot in Jupyter and my local RStudio. While there is no difference in the resolution of the plotted elements, the resolution of text is low in the Jupyter version.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist))+geom_point()+
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))
ggsave('plot.png', width=10, height=8)
```

[Jupyter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FprJc.png)
[RStudio plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdde.png)

The problem remains if I use another method to export (other than ggsave).
I also tried increasing the resolution with `repr`

```
options(repr.plot.width=16, repr.plot.height=12, repr.plot.res=400)
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Hmm....I'm not seeing that so it is hard to test solutions. Go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/r#specifying-an-r-environment-with-a-runtimetxt-file) and press the launch badge that is to the right side of 'Jupyter+R:'. Run the notebook and you'll see the run produces smaller output versions than it had from the old run when it opened. (I know the fix for that one, `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = c("text/plain", "image/svg+xml" ))` - see [here](http://compbio.ucsd.edu/outputting-beautiful-jupyter-notebooks-r-kernel-edition/)). But I don't see what you report with your code there.